# Python scripts is eating my memory keeps growing till it eats all of the ram

Tags: python, memory-management, cpu-usage, ram, allocation

i have a python script which is running with ros and subscribing to a topic which returns a point cloud with velocity xyz and intensity information from radar

and when i launch the script which takes this information and does some processing to this data the memory usage keeps growing infinitely

here is the python code

```
    def callback(self,msg):

    self.pts = msg.velocity
    self.header = msg.header
   

    
def ros_to_pcl(self,ros_cloud):
    points_list = []

    for data in pc2.read_points(ros_cloud, skip_nans=True):
        points_list.append([data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3],data[4]])

    pcl_data = pcl.PointCloud_PointXYZRGB()
    pcl_data.from_list(points_list)

    return pcl_data

def pcl_to_ros(self,pcl_array):
    ros_msg = PointCloud2()

    ros_msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    ros_msg.header.frame_id = "ti_mmwave_0"

    ros_msg.height = 1
    ros_msg.width = pcl_array.size

    ros_msg.fields.append(PointField(
                            name="x",
                            offset=0,
                            datatype=PointField.FLOAT32, count=1))
    ros_msg.fields.append(PointField(
                            name="y",
                            offset=4,
                            datatype=PointField.FLOAT32, count=1))
    ros_msg.fields.append(PointField(
                            name="z",
                            offset=8,
                            datatype=PointField.FLOAT32, count=1))
    ros_msg.fields.append(PointField(
                            name="rgb",
                            offset=16,
                            datatype=PointField.FLOAT32, count=1))                       

    ros_msg.is_bigendian = False
    ros_msg.point_step = 32
    ros_msg.row_step = ros_msg.point_step * ros_msg.width * ros_msg.height
    ros_msg.is_dense = False
    buffer = []

    for data in pcl_array:
        s = struct.pack('>f', data[3])
        i = struct.unpack('>l', s)[0]
        pack = ctypes.c_uint32(i).value

        r = (pack & 0x00FF0000) >> 16
        g = (pack & 0x0000FF00) >> 8
        b = (pack & 0x000000FF)

        buffer.append(struct.pack('ffffBBBBIII', data[0], data[1], data[2], 1.0, b, g, r, 0, 0, 0, 0))

    ros_msg.data = b"".join(buffer)

    return ros_msg
def transform_cloud(self,cloud):
    try:
        trans = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform('ti_mmwave_0', cloud.header.frame_id,
                                            cloud.header.stamp,
                                            rospy.Duration(0.1))
    except tf2.LookupException as ex:
        rospy.logwarn(str(lookup_time.to_sec()))
        rospy.logwarn(ex)
        return
    except tf2.ExtrapolationException as ex:
        rospy.logwarn(str(lookup_time.to_sec()))
        rospy.logwarn(ex)
        return
    cloud_out = do_transform_cloud(cloud, trans)
    return cloud_out    

def estimate_number_of_clusters(self,downsampled_list):
    #scaler = StandardScaler()
    downsampled_list_np=np.array(downsampled_list)
    #downsampled_list_np=scaler.fit_transform(downsampled_list_np)
    
    Data = {'x':downsampled_list_np[:,0],'y':downsampled_list_np[:,1]}#,'z':downsampled_list_np[:,2]}
    
   
    df = DataFrame(Data,columns=['x','y'])#,'z']) 
    #scaler = StandardScaler()
    #df_scaled =  scaler.fit_transform(df)  
    clustering=DBSCAN(eps=0.35,min_samples=8).fit(df)
    #if df['x'].max()< 7 :
        #clustering=DBSCAN(eps=0.35,min_samples=8).fit(df)
        #clustering=DBSCAN(eps=0.,min_samples=8).fit(df)
    #else :
        #clustering=DBSCAN(eps=0.1,min_samples=2).fit(df) 
    cluster=clustering.labels_
    number_of_clusters=len(set(cluster))
    
    Data_new= {'x':downsampled_list_np[:,0],'y':downsampled_list_np[:,1],'z':downsampled_list_np[:,2],'intensity':downsampled_list_np[:,3],'velocity':downsampled_list_np[:,4],'label':cluster}
    df_new= DataFrame(Data_new)
   
    return df_new,number_of_clusters
      




def pcl_callback(self,data):
    #cloud_new=self.ros_to_pcl(data)
    """seg = cloud_new.make_segmenter()
     #Set the model you wish to fit 
    seg.set_model_type(pcl.SACMODEL_PLANE)
    seg.set_method_type(pcl.SAC_RANSAC)
    # Max distance for a point to be considered fitting the model
    # Experiment with different values for max_distance 
    max_distance = 0.004
    seg.set_distance_threshold(max_distance)
    # Call the segment function to obtain set of inlier indices and model coefficients
    inliers, coefficients = seg.segment()

    extracted_ground   = cloud_new.extract(inliers, negative=False)

    extracted_objects = cloud_new.extract(inliers, negative=True)"""

    #out=self.pcl_to_ros(cloud_new)
    #out_trans=self.transform_cloud(out)

    
    
    downsampled_list=[]
    for data in pc2.read_points(data,field_names = ("x", "y", "z","intensity","velocity"),skip_nans=True):
        downsampled_list.append([data[0], data[1], data[2],data[3],data[4]])
    print("bla bla bla ", sys.getsizeof(downsampled_list))    
    #print(downsampled_list)

    df_grouped,optimal_number_of_clusters=self.estimate_number_of_clusters(downsampled_list)
    #print('Number of clusters : {}'.format(optimal_number_of_clusters))
    fig1,ax1 = plt.subplots()#plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7))
    fig2,ax2 = plt.subplots()
    #ax = Axes3D(fig)
    df_saif = self.feature_extraction(df_grouped)
    
    
    #heatmaps plotting
    
    df_grouped["range"] = df_grouped.apply(lambda a : sqrt(a.x*a.x + a.y*a.y + a.z*a.z),axis=1)
    heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(df_grouped["range"], df_grouped["velocity"], bins=1000,range = [[0,20],[-3,3]])
    heatmap = gaussian_filter(heatmap, sigma=32)
    extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
    
    
   

    
    
    print('df saif : \n',df_saif)
    for index in df_saif.label.unique() :#grp_name, grp_idx in df_grouped.groupby('label').groups.items():
        y = df_grouped[df_grouped.label == index]["y"]
        x = df_grouped[df_grouped.label == index]["x"]
        z = df_grouped[df_grouped.label == index]["z"]
        ax1.scatter(x,y)
        df_ayoub = df_saif[df_saif["label"]==index]
        df_ayoub = df_ayoub.reset_index()
        ax1.add_patch(Rectangle((df_ayoub["corner0"][0],df_ayoub["corner1"][0]),df_ayoub.length[0],df_ayoub.width[0],edgecolor="green",fill=True,lw=4,facecolor="none"))
        ax1.annotate(str(self.velocity_std), xy=(x.mean(),y.mean()), xytext=(-7,7), textcoords='offset points')
        
        
        
    
    
    
    #axis configurattion
    ax1.set_xlim(0,20)
    ax1.set_ylim(-20,20)
    ax2.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, origin='lower', cmap=cm.jet)
    ax2.locator_params('x', nbins=1)
    ax2.set_xlabel('range')
    ax2.set_ylabel('velocity')
    ax1.set_xlabel('x')
    ax1.set_ylabel('y')
    
    
    #Plot bot figures
    fig1.canvas.draw()
    fig2.canvas.draw()        
    img = np.frombuffer(fig1.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)
    img2 = np.frombuffer(fig2.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)

    img = img.reshape(fig1.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
    img2 = img2.reshape(fig2.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))

    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    
    
    cv2.imshow("plot",img)
    cv2.imshow("heatmap",img2)
    self.count = self.count + 1
    #self.CNN(img2) 
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('heatmaps', 'img__{}.png'.format(self.count)),img2)
    #self.calibration(df_grouped,self.count)
    

    #plt.show()  
def feature_extraction(self,df_new) :
    df_final = []
    #fields = ['num','width','length','S','density','x_std','y_std','range_mean','l','range_std','i_peak']
    #writer = csv.DictWriter(open(sys.argv[1],'w'),fields)
    #writer.writeheader()
    #print("df_new",df_new)
    for i in df_new.label.unique() :
        if i != -1 :
            #data = pd.DataFrame()
            df = df_new[df_new["label"]==i]
            df = df.reset_index()
            #print("df :",df)
            #df.drop(["index"],axis=1,inplace=True)
            num = df.shape[0]
            x_max = df['x'].max() 
            x_min = df['x'].min() 
            y_max = df['y'].max() 
            y_min = df['y'].min() 
            width = y_max - y_min
            length = x_max - x_min
            corner = (x_min,y_min)
            S = width * length
            density = num/S
            x_std = df.x.std()
            y_std = df.y.std()
            self.velocity_std = df.velocity.mean()
            df["range"] = df.apply(lambda a : sqrt(a.x*a.x + a.y*a.y + a.z*a.z),axis=1)
            range_mean = df.range.mean()
            l = df.range.max() - df.range.min()
            range_std = df.range.std()
            i_peak = df.intensity.max()
            """with open("features.csv","a+") as f :
                csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
                csv_writer.writerow([num,width,length,S,density,x_std,y_std,range_mean,l,range_std,i_peak])"""
            #data["corner0"] = corner[0]
            #data["corner1"] = corner[1]    
            #data["width"] = width
            #data["length"] = length
            #data["label"] = i
            df_final.append([corner[0],corner[1],width,length,i])
            outfile=open('velocity3.csv','a')
            filecsv=csv.writer(outfile,delimiter=';')
            filecsv.writerow([num,width,length,S,density,x_std,y_std,range_mean,l,range_std,i_peak,self.velocity_std])
            outfile.close()
            #writer.writerow({'num': num ,'width' : width,'length' : length,'S' : S,'density': density,'x_std' : x_std,'y_std' : y_std,'range_mean' : range_mean ,'l' : l ,'range_std' : range_std ,'i_peak': i_peak})
    dataframe_f=pd.DataFrame(columns=['corner0','corner1','width','length','label'],data= df_final)
    #print("frames:\n",dataframe_f)
    return dataframe_f
               
def calibration(self,df_grouped,counter) :
    _, frame = self.cam.read() 
    for index in df_grouped.label.unique() :
        if df_grouped[df_grouped.label == index]["velocity"].mean() > 0.8 :
            x = df_grouped[df_grouped.label == index]["x"].mean()
            y = df_grouped[df_grouped.label == index]["y"].mean()
            z = df_grouped[df_grouped.label == index]["z"].mean()
            img_name = 'img_{}.png'.format(counter)
            outfile=open('calibration.csv','a')
            filecsv=csv.writer(outfile,delimiter=';')
            filecsv.writerow([x,y,z,img_name])
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('calibration', 'img_{}.png'.format(counter)),frame)
    
            
"""def CNN(self,img) :
    img=cv2.resize(img,(224,224))
    img = img.reshape(1,224,224,3)
    y_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(img, dtype=tf.int64) 
    json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
    # load weights into new model
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

        loaded_model.load_weights("model_inception.h5")
    predictions = loaded_model.predict(y_tensor)
    y_pred = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
    print("predictions array",y_pred)"""
    
   def main(args):
       rospy.init_node('cluster_pointcloud', anonymous=True)
       cp = cluster_pointcloud()

       try:
           rospy.spin()
       except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
           pass

       if __name__ == '__main__':
           main(sys.argv)
```

it's quite a long script sorry for that and i would appreciate if anyone would help me identify why this python code is using a lot of memory and what exactly is allocating this memory

Comment: You may want to try out a tool like [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) to find out where memory is being used the most in your code and go from there.

Comment: i figured out that it's the matplotlib fig2 plotting that is taking a lot of memory but i don't know how to optimize it do you have any idea ?

Comment: the matplotlib library isn't likely to be the right place to try and optimize — it's likely that you're either using the wrong tool for the task (does it have to be matplotlib? does it have to be that specific function you're using?) or you're making calls too many times (can you render a plot once at the end instead of multiple times?)